# How to add temp table to another temp table with extra column

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql

```
CREATE TABLE #EmpPcodes
(
   YearMonth        INT,
   YEAR             INT,
   MONTH            INT,
   RunNo            INT,
   Amount           NUMERIC(18, 3),
   GroupCode        NvarCHAR(30),
   GroupName        NvarCHAR(250),
   GroupAName       NvarCHAR(250),
   PayrollGroup     INT,
   EmployeeId       INT
)    
CREATE TABLE #pArrangeAllcode
(
   YearMonth        INT,
   YEAR             INT,
   MONTH            INT,
   RunNo            INT,
   Amount           NUMERIC(18, 3),
   GroupCode        NvarCHAR(30),
   GroupName        NvarCHAR(250),
   GroupAName       NvarCHAR(250),
   PayrollGroup     INT,
   EmployeeId       INT,
   CodeArrange      INT
)

INSERT INTO #pArrangeAllcode 
SELECT YearMonth, YEAR, MONTH, RunNo, Amount, GroupCode, GroupName, 
GroupAName, PayrollGroup, EmployeeId,
FROM dbo.#EmpPcodes 

SELECT * FROM #pArrangeAllcode
```

I expect to get the data from the #EmPcodes temp table to #pArrangeAllcode
but it has extra column that I'll use it later ... I always get this error :

```
Insert Error: Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.
```

Any Help ?

Comment: Simple rule:  Always list all the columns when you are using `insert`.

Comment: so do I have to insert the values in the CodeArrange in the insert !

Comment: The problem that I have an update statement from the #EmpCodes to add them in the new temp Table #pArrangeAllcode

Comment: Tag the dbms used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you are missing one column in insert statement whch also need some value:

use this:

```
INSERT INTO #pArrangeAllcode 
SELECT YearMonth, YEAR, MONTH, RunNo, Amount, GroupCode, GroupName, 
GroupAName, PayrollGroup, EmployeeId,NULL
FROM dbo.#EmpPcodes
```

Answer (score 1):

Use below query for inserting records.

```
INSERT INTO #pArrangeAllcode 
SELECT YearMonth, YEAR, MONTH, RunNo, Amount, GroupCode, GroupName, 
GroupAName, PayrollGroup, EmployeeId,NULL
FROM dbo.#EmpPcodes
```

Answer (score 1):

`CodeArrange` is the extra column exist in the `#pArrangeAllcode` table. Since it is `NOT NULL` column, you can skip the particular column name in the insert block and explicitly mention the column name is the INSERT statement.

```
INSERT INTO #pArrangeAllcode (YearMonth, YEAR, MONTH, RunNo, Amount, GroupCode, GroupName, GroupAName, PayrollGroup, EmployeeId)
SELECT YearMonth, YEAR, MONTH, RunNo, Amount, GroupCode, GroupName, GroupAName, PayrollGroup, EmployeeId
FROM #EmpPcodes
```

or if you want to store some dummy value in the `CodeArrange` column then pass `NULL`

```
INSERT INTO #pArrangeAllcode (YearMonth, YEAR, MONTH, RunNo, Amount, GroupCode, GroupName, GroupAName, PayrollGroup, EmployeeId, CodeArrange)
SELECT YearMonth, YEAR, MONTH, RunNo, Amount, GroupCode, GroupName, GroupAName, PayrollGroup, EmployeeId, NULL
FROM #EmpPcodes
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO #pArrangeAllcode 
SELECT dbo.#EmpPcodes.*, NULL
FROM dbo.#EmpPcodes
```